# Error with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

Hello I am a young Belgian developer and follow currently a tutorial on YouTube to create a Drawer Navigation but I get errors when launching the emulator due.
[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zuo3n-DjF7w) is the Tutorial.

**Here are the errors :**

```
02-10 11:31:12.432 2297-2297/com.example.flori.mylordring E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.flori.mylordring, PID: 2297
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flori.mylordring/com.example.flori.mylordring.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.flori.mylordring.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**And Main code :**

```
package com.example.flori.mylordring;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static ImageButton imgView;
private int test;
int [] images = {R.drawable.im1,R.drawable.im2,R.drawable.im3,R.drawable.im4,R.drawable.im5,R.drawable.im6,R.drawable.im7};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Rolololo", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }



public void image(View view){
imgView=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
test++;
test = test % images.length;
imgView.setImageResource(images[test]);
            }
        }
        );
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
 // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
 // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();

//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
return true;
        }

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Activity code (I have 2 different activities and this is the content_main, i also have activity_main) :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:background="#e2656262"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.flori.mylordring.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragmentholder">
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/navlist"
android:background="#dedede"
android:layout_gravity="start"
/>

    <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello World!"
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton
android:onClick="image"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imageButton"
android:src="@drawable/im1"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**the Manifest code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.flori.mylordring">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

**</manifest>
```

**and my2 styles.xml :**
this is my style.xml :**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**Style.xml(V21) :**

```
<resources>>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

In this part of code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); //will return null
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//why set it after you call getSupportActionBar?
```

As you can see above you are getting the actionbar before set the toolbar as your actionbar, which will return null.

you need to switch those so you will get the reference from your toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Or in another words, you could use `getSupportActionBar()`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); // First initialize the Toolbar
setSupportActionBar(toolbar); // Set as SupportActionBar

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); // do your stuffs
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And the second problem is:

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Which you set it for `Drawer` and it shouldn't be there, check this link:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout#expanding-and-collapsing-toolbars

> Add an `app:layout_behavior` to a `RecyclerView` or any other View capable
>   of nested scrolling such as `NestedScrollView`. The support library
>   contains a special string resource
>   `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` that maps to
>   AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior, which is used to notify the
>   AppBarLayout when scroll events occur on this particular view